# Calling python scripts from anywehre

Tags: python, unix, path

I have a collection of python scripts that import from each other.  If I want to use these in a location where the scripts are not physically present, how can I do this. I tried adding the path of the dir with the scripts to my $PATH but got no joy.  Any help appreciated, thanks.

Comment: add the dir to your pythonpath

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python doesn't share its own path with the general `$PATH`, so to be able to do what you're looking for, you must add your scripts in the `$PYTHONPATH` instead.

Answer (score 1):

As [@Spirine](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3738866/spirine) mentions, you will need to add it to your `$PYTHONPATH`.

If you are using bash, you can add the following to your `.bashrc`:

`export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/path/to/python/scripts`